# Customizing Bootstrap while using in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am using Bootstrap to design my Meteor app. I am using this package

```
twbs:bootstrap
```

Its working fine, the only problem I am facing is that I want to use the functionality of bootstraps customization like here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/nemo64/bootstrap works great I use it. This package will generate `custom.bootstrap.import.less` for you to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this package to easily customise Bootstrap in Meteor:
https://atmospherejs.com/nemo64/bootstrap

(As was mentioned in the comments already)